# How can i resolve a define error for the gcc precompiler in winnt.h file?

Tags: c, gcc, window

I want to use the gcc precompiler to generate dependencies, I can compile with visual studio without a problem and the Software is working properly. 
When i putted in make file the command for the gcc precompiler, I had an error

```
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\Windows\v6.0A\Include/winnt.h:81:2: error: #error 
"No Target Architecture"
```

What could i define to resolve this issue?
I tried to change the command of gcc like this :

```
$(__GCC_COMPIL) $(__PATHES_GCC) -E -DSOME_TARGET -MM $(@:.obj=.c) -MT $@ -MF $(@:.obj=.dep)
```

I tried with some targets like `_IA64_` or `_WIN64` but without success.

winnt.h code:

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
   #if defined(_AMD64_)
      #define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD )
   #elif defined(_IA64_)
      #define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) (TYPE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) > TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD) ? \
                          TYPE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) : TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD ))
   #else
      #error "No Target Architecture"
   #endif

   #define PROBE_ALIGNMENT32( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD )

#else
   #define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD )
#endif
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i posted it.

Comment: @LPS i posted that with visual studio i have a working software, the problem is on GCC.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre
`@$(__GCC_COMPIL) $(__PATHES_GCC) -E -D_WIN64 -MM $(@:.obj=.c) -MT $@ -MF $(@:.obj=.dep)`

Comment: If you pass `-D_WIN64`, you enter the first `#if`. Then you have to pass either `-D_AMD64_` or `-D_IA64_` _besides_ `-D_WIN64`